# $H$-Field and $B$-Field Directions

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

When it comes to the $\mathbf H$-field and $\mathbf B$-field created by some material with a current I passing through it, they will always face the same way, right? Since whether the material is Diamagnetic or Paramagnetic doesn't matter as the permeability for both cases is always $>0$.

Does that mean that the only field that can "face the other way" should be the $\mathbf{M}$-Field? Since $\mathbf{M}=\chi_m\mathbf{H}$ and $\chi_m < 0$ for diamagnetics.

Comment: When you are talking about magnetic fields created by current, are you excluding permanent magnets from the discussion? Within permanent magnets $\vec H$ and $\vec B$ are normally in opposite directions.

Comment: yes, I am excluding permanent magnets.